# need to access child infoWindow of google maps marker in angular 5

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have an Angular 5 app that uses Angular Google Maps(AGM) https://angular-maps.com/. I have code where if you click on an item in a list from one component it opens a child infoWindow of a specific marker in a separate map component. I do this by changing the attribute isOpen in the infoWindow component. I want to be able to close any opened infoWindows when a new infoWindow is opened. I can't figure out how to get the instance of the child infoWindow associated with a specific marker.

This is the map component HTML:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker id="{{ m.id }}" *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index"
    [latitude]="m.latitude" [longitude]="m.longitude"
    [markerDraggable]="false" [iconUrl]="iconMarker" [openInfoWindow]="true">
      <agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false" [isOpen]="m.isOpen">
        <strong>{{ m.name }}<br>
        {{ m.address }}<br>
        {{ m.city }}, {{ m.state }} {{ m.zipcode }}
      </agm-info-window>
    </agm-marker>
    <mapcontent (onMapLoad)='loadAPIWrapper($event)'></mapcontent>
  </agm-map>
```

This is the map component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.markersService.currentMarker.subscribe(
      (marker: Object) => {
        this.currentMarker = marker;
        this.isOpen = false;
        if ( this.currentMarker && this._map ) {
          this.markerZoom();
        }
    });
}
public loadAPIWrapper(map) {
        this._map = map;
      }
public markerZoom(){
        this.currentMarker.isOpen = true;
        const latlng = <LatLngLiteral>{
          lat: this.currentMarker.latitude, lng: this.currentMarker.longitude
        };
        this._map.setCenter( latlng );
        this._map.setZoom(9);

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work using ViewChild. I found a different solution. I use the isOpen property in the infowindow component. Before I set the current marker's infowindow to open by setting isOpen to true I loop through all of the markers and set isOpen to false. I rather not use a foreach loop but it was the only solution I found that worked.

```
public markerZoom(){
    this.markers.forEach((i) => i.isOpen = false); //closes any opened infowindows
    this.currentMarker.isOpen = true;
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@ViewChild(infoWindow) infoWindow:Window
```

if your child component is single,

and if you want to get list of you child component's

you can use

```
@ViewChildren
```

to get all child component's by component type.

hope this will help u .